# Selecting more than 5 columns in my SQL query is slowing it down 

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am running a simple SQL query in SQL Server Management Studio (which I am actually executing in my application also) and I found this interesting. I'm hoping someone can explain what is wrong with it.

The database table has 25 columns, 5 columns are indexed and one primary key column exists.
Except for one column, all the rest of the columns are of type `varchar` of lengths <= 50 or `datetime` or `int`. That one exception is that the column is of type `varchar(512)` (let's call this column `BigColumn`)

My query is this:

```
Select PKColumn, column1, column2, column3, column4, column5
from database_table
where PKColumn = value
```

The query executes faster (< 1sec) when I select 5 or fewer columns. I can select any 5 columns except the `BigColumn` (along with PK, of course) and the result comes back in < 1sec. But, if I select more than 5 columns the query slows down considerably (result comes back 6 secs). Also, if I select `PKColumn` and `BigColumn` the result comes back in 6 secs.

Does anyone know what the problem might be? I did put in a request for our DBA to look into this, but I want to know if anyone has faced a problem like this and how they resolved it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the execution plan for each slow/fast query?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have enough permissions on this particular DB to view the execution plan, this being a prod DB. But I looked at the execution plan on the non-prod(they both have same schema). And it says select cost 0% and its doing a Clustered Index Seek. It is same on both queries. (Both queries execute fast in non-prod DB).

Comment: Well if the schema is identical, down to the indexes I would wildly speculate either different index fragmentation, different stats or different editions of SQL Server

Comment: Without `SHOWPLAN` permission what is the output if you do `SET STATISTICS IO ON` then run slow and fast queries?

Comment: Hi Martin, Thanks for the comment and sorry for not responding faster.  I tried with set statistics io on and that made the query to execute much slower.  I am not sure if that is supposed to do that.
Anyways, the results are the same for both queries.  I did a select on PK only and still the results were the same:  
_logical reads 3, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0._
I will also keep you posted on when I hear anything about this from the DBA.

Comment: Hi Ravi,  you have left out some important detail.  How big is the table (how many rows of data)?  Is the database on your local machine (I am assuming that it is not as you need to speak to a DBA about performance)?  What is your network speed like?  Are you querying the db over a vpn connection?

Comment: Hi Andrew,The table has about 100,000 records, so it is not a huge one. The issue is only with production database. Both the production and stage databases are in a different domain than our regular work domain.  I tried somethign else today that baffles me more:
I wrote a small console app which uses ado.net to query that prod database table and print out the query execution times (including opening connection).  Running the app from Win 7 printed out query execution time of 16 secs, whereas running the app from Win Xp printed out time of 0.3 sec. No such issues when connecting to stage db.

Comment: @RaviC - 3 logical reads is nothing. That query ought to complete in miliseconds. Maybe you are encountering blocking from other transactions on the table which may explain the wildly varying times you describe.

Comment: Our infrastructure team thinks that this is a network issues.  They are working on it.  I will post the issue/solution once we figure it out.

Comment: I finally found the solution from a Microsoft forum **([Forum Link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowscompatibility/thread/f295994c-5812-4e46-8ac9-f05471d4dd54?prof=required), see second from last post)**. On the web server (and my windows 7 computer) I had to **disable "Receive Window auto-tuning"**. Now the database connection is faster and also the queries are running faster (execution times in milli secs) Thank you all for your responses.

Comment: Ravi C, You should Post your comment and as an answer to your question and then accept it as the correct answer.